# DIV not appearing in IE8

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the basic layout for a webpage.  The first green div is appearing, but the second div 'bottomtest' is not.  Does anyone know why?  I'm using IE8.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>    
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="toptest" style="height:200px; width:auto; background-color:green;" />
 <div class="bottomtest" style="background-color:blue; height:500px; width:auto;" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/), which can't be helping.

Comment: How is it invalid?  Do you know why the second div isn't appearing below the first div?

Comment: The validator I linked to will tell you how it is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The second div has no content (or end tag for that matter), has a width of `auto` and is `float`ing. Floating elements shrink wrap their content, so your div will be shrunk until it is 0px wide (this problem is not limited to IE8).

… you appear to have edited your question to remove the `float` property from the style attribute. This answer should still solve the problem you originally asked about. If you are trying to create a reduced test case, then read [The SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (in short: make sure that you test the code you ask about to make sure it is valid, shows the problem you actually have and doesn't introduce new problems).

Comment: What should it look like so the green div is on the top and the blue div is on the bottom?

Comment: It does not.  What should my code look like so that the green div is on top of the blue div?

Answer (score 0):

You need to close both of your divs properly to fix this error.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="toptest" style="height:200px; width:auto; background-color:green;"></div>
        <div class="bottomtest" style="background-color:blue; height:500px; width:auto;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]